# Current limits and sensors power consumption

Tags: power-supply, automation

I have example sensors datasheets:

[1sensor](http://www.balluff.com/balluff/MDE/en/products/catalogue/products_details.jsp?id=BMF00C4-179526)
[2sensor](http://www.balluff.com/balluff/MPL/pl/products/catalogue/products_details.jsp?id=BES00A4-127337)
[3sensor](http://www.balluff.com/balluff/MPL/pl/products/catalogue/products_details.jsp?id=BOS01JK-221968)

And I have supply current limited to 0.5 A.

Which current from datasheets should I take for calculations if my supply is sufficient?

There are:

- effective operating current
- no load current Io damped max
- max no load current Io undamped
- off state current Ir max

I thought that I should take effective operating current. But I saw working systems with 8 sensors with effective operating current 200mA supplied from 0.5A limited supply.

So the main question is **which current should I take for calculations**? And the second question is: **could someone explain clearly what this four current values from datasheets mean and for what purpose they serve**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to the first datasheet,

Looks to me like 200mA **(Effective operating current Ie**) is the maximum load current through the output (PNP) transistor. **Bemessungsbetriebsstrom** is "rated current".

6mA (**No-load current Io damped max.**) and 3mA (**Max. no-load cur. Io undamped**) are the maximum power supply currents depending on whether it "sees" metal (the internal oscillator is damped) or not. This does not include any load current, of course. Diagram from [here](http://www.altechcorp.com/PDFS/SENSOR1.PDF).

[image]

Off-state current is the maximum leakage of the PNP transistor (in other words if you need the output voltage to be less than (say) 0.4V, you should use a load resistor of less than 5K).

So, your power supply current for eight sensors should be 8 times 6mA = 48mA plus whatever the total of all loads adds up to.

With a 500mA power supply you could have >50mA per load.

I have no idea what "Short circuit current 100A" means, it really seems like it could be a typo. Most such sensors from reputable makers have some kind of short-circuit output protection, but 300mA~1A would be more like it. Nothing like that number appears in the current catalog [here](http://www.balluff.com/downloads/895102_1302_EN.pdf).